# notepad++ find number greater than a specific number

Tags: find, notepad++

I have logs with some random numbers.

What I want to do is find numbers greater than a specific number, eg : **find all number > 1234567.**

Can anybody help?

Comment: I don't think its possible given that the digit count can be anything. You can do a numerical range check in Regex but given that in your case the ceiling is infinity, I doubt its possible or even feasible to use regular expressions

Comment: If numbers are at the beginning of the line, you could sort lines. If not, you could use regex search-and-replace to move them there first. Keep in mind though that it isn't numerical sort, so you'll get 10 before 2 and so on. But it might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A weird regex (not sure it's really usefull) :

```
\d{8,}|123456[8-9]|12345[7-9]\d|1234[6-9]\d{2}|123[5-9]\d{3}|12[4-9]\d{4}|1[3-9]\d{5}|[2-9]\d{6}\b
```

It works only for the number `1234567` you have to modify it for another number.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Notepad++'s Python Script plugin. Not the best solution, but it works!

1. Install Python Script plugin, from Plugin Manager or from the [official website](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).
2. Then go to Plugins > Python Script > New Script. Choose a filename for your new file (eg find_numbers.py) and copy the code that follows.
3. Run Plugins > Python Script > Scripts > find_numbers.py and a new window will show the matched numbers.

```py
from re import finditer

number = 1234567

console.clear()
console.show()
content = editor.getText()
for row, line in enumerate(content.split('\n')):
    for m in re.finditer(r'[0-9]+', line):
        if int(m.group(0)) > number:
            console.write('row %d, col %d-%d: %s\n' % (row, m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0)))
```

So for example take this text:

```
This is a test 1234568
with asome pretty big numbers 0 1234567
Can anybody help?
999999999999 99999999
123
```

The above solution will return you this:

```
row 0, col 15-22: 1234568
row 3, col 0-12: 999999999999
row 3, col 13-21: 99999999
```

You can obviously change the script to output the information in any way you prefer.

Comment: I personally had to change `from re import finditer` to `import re`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that can't get that to work change the first line into these 2 lines.

import re

from re import finditer