# Notepad C++ finding numbers bigger than X

Tags: numbers, notepad++

Is there any script or possibility to do this?

I mean, i have opened 30 files in notepad with numers in them. I need to find numbers bigger than 5000.

Is this possible? I tried using this, but notepad crashes. [notepad++ find number greater than a specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406141/notepad-find-number-greater-than-a-specific-number)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following regular expression

```
[5-9]\d{3}|\d{4}\d+
```

Comment: but where to put this?

Comment: The original re had a problem which I now fixed. It looks either for 4 digit number starting from 5-9 or for more than 4 digit number.