# how to find numbers greater then a specific number

Tags: python, notepad++

I am mainly using the notepad++ but the script i m trying to run with python just does not work.

I do have many lines of containing Numbers, I need to mark line where is number greater then 300 For example. They are with comma sometimes (for example: 20,5 Etc..)

Can anyone help me ? please

Tried:
 [notepad++ find number greater than a specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406141/notepad-find-number-greater-than-a-specific-number)

If you have any other solution/Text editor which can do it. Let me know please

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you thinking of onboard tools, like the regex search npp offers? Or are you looking for outside solutions? Which language? You might want to tag the language. You should show your own coding attempts, in order to avoid the impression of looking for a free coding service. When you have time, take the [tour].

Comment: Well i tried this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406141/notepad-find-number-greater-than-a-specific-number

Its not working

Comment: If you tried to adapt one of the answers to that question, then please show your code and explain how it failed.

Comment: Toto, this is not duplicate, i said its not working.

Comment: PaulJ: Both answers in the duplicate question use the `re` module to find the lines of interest—in your case, you'll need to use a different regular expression, and do something different when there's a match, but otherwise it's exactly the same.